# Generic or overloaded methods

Tags: c#, generics, overloading

i have three methods. what would be the best way to combine them into one.

```
public App Get(customobj data, string x)
{
    return null;
}

public Con Get(customobj data, string x)
{
    return null;
}

public Env Get(customobj data, string x)
{
    return null;
}
```

Comment: What are you doing in those methods determines whether you need Generic or overloaded methods.

Comment: The best way would be inheritance of your return types (if possible) or: not at all. Three seperate methods is perfectly fine if you have three different return types.

Comment: Is `App`, `Con` and `Env` related in any way?

Comment: _"i have three methods"_ This won't compile as you have the same signature for all three method calls with the same name.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a nice little generic:

```
public static TOutput Get<TOutput>(this customobj data, string x)
```

Keep in mind that implementing a class behind this that uses the factory pattern is probably the best implementation, but that's really up to you. You could easily just switch on the type name and build the right type.

Using this would look like this:

```
myCustomObj.Get<Con>("my x val");
```

Comment: How would you call this?  I imagine the syntax would not look "nice".

Comment: Generics are for accomodating different datatype. How this will help in combining different functions with *same* parameters together?

Comment: @kirkWoll You would call this by explicit passing the type parameters: Get<Type1, Type2>(data, x)

Comment: @user2674389, and he made it an extension method, which is pretty confusing if you also have to pass in the type of the object being extended.

Comment: What was that that Eric Lippert said?  Whenever you're switching on TYPE in a generic method there is probably something wrong with your code?  While your solution does in fact work, perhaps it's not the best way to tackle this design problem.

Comment: @KirkWoll, thanks for the feedback on that. I got a little confused for a moment. Have a look at my edit and let me know your thoughts. The syntax on this would be something like `myCustomObj.Get<Con>("myx val");`

Comment: @neoistheone, ah, apologies, missed that edit.  (And your code is perfectly fine now, but because the OP omitted too much info, I have no idea of its efficacy to the problem at hand. :))

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer to your question is there is no best way. Unless the code in all three is going to be identical (unlikely as they return three different types), keep them as three methods as any attempt to combine them into one will make the code messier, harder to read and thus harder to maintain. Further, give them better names, which describe what each one does. As a minimum, something like:

```
public App GetApp(customobj data, string x)
{
    ...
}

public Con GetCon(customobj data, string x)
{
    ...
}

public Env GetEnv(customobj data, string x)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: sorry for the question being so open..yeah they will not be identical..they are going to perform get differently...and yes the implementation was getting messier when i tried to merge them..so thought of asking if i can get something around it...anyways thanks i am going to keep them the way they are..

Answer (score 0):

AS far as i understand your question. you can create a Class

```
Public parameter
{
   App app;
   Con con;
   Env env;
}
public parameter Get(customobj data, string x)
{
    parameter _pobj=new parameter();
    //you can add the result here if you want or else return null.
    _pobj="somehting1";
    _pobj="somthing2";
    _pobj="somthing3";

    return _pobj;
}
```

you can collect them in a different call by saying _pobj.env or the mentioned parameters